# Check whether user open the site first time or session expired in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am using the following code to redirect to login page if session expire :

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Count == 0 || HttpContext.Current.Session["UserRole"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData["Error"] = "Your Session have expired. Please relogin again.";
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index_Partial", controller = "Home" }));
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    Data = new
                    {
                        error = true,
                        message = "Your Session have expired. Please relogin again."
                    }
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 501;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            }
            else
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }));
        }
    }
```

everything working fine using the above code.

**Problem :**

User open the site i am showing Welcome message then if user click on any item in tree view in site as all items are available only for authenticated users then message should be ""Please Login"" as user didn't have any active session before but by checking session as in above code i am able to show only single message.

"Your Session have expired. Please relogin again."

Please let me know if still scenario is not clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably you need to create a custom authorization filter as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the cookie to save the user logging info, use Session to check if current user should log in again. if the cookie is null or empty, then show "please log in".

Comment: But i want to do this without cookies

Comment: @Sunny If you want to do it without cookies, then you are going to have to implement some kind of server side record (perhaps IP address, if that is enough) of visitors to your site, and last access time.

Comment: @Sunny actually session was based on cookie. As Miika L said that  implementing some kind of server side record, but it's impossible to check whether the user has logged on or not.